# Ubuntu 13.04 stuck on shutdown due to bbswitch

Tags: 13.04, shutdown, bbswitch

I had this problem long ago, but it's the first time it's caused, I think, by bbswitch. First the Ubuntu logo is shown, then I get this :

[image]

(the last thing written there is `bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics`)

PS. I can hear the fan and the hard drive turning off, but the screen stays the same and the laptop still quit hot.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my xps15. Try editing /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and changing:

TrunCardOffAtExit=false

To:

TurnCardOffAtExit=true

I can't say for sure it's fixed but I have not had the issue since.